# Adding a string to an array adds all characters separately

Tags: python-3.x

Any suggestion how to merge it better so the dual digits numbers does not split?
Sorry for bad english.

```
def merge(strArr):
    newList = []
    for x in range(len(strArr)):
        newList += strArr[x]
    return newList

array_test = ["1, 3, 4, 7, 13", "1, 2, 4, 13, 15"]
print(merge(array_test))
```

output =['1', ',', ' ', '3', ',', ' ', '4', ',', ' ', '7', ',', ' ', '1', '3', '1', ',', ' ', '2', ',', ' ', '4', ',', ' ', '1', '3', ',', ' ', '1', '5']`

expected output= [1,2,3,4,7,13,1,2,4,13,15]

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: just the numbers

Comment: because you take each inner string and add each character of each inner string to your return-list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result becomes the way it is, because you take each inner string and add each character of it to your return-list without removing any spaces or commas.

You can change your code to:

```
def merge(strArr):
    new_list = []
    for inner in strArr:
        new_list.extend(inner.split(", "))  # split and extend instead of += (== append)

    return new_list


array_test =["1, 3, 4, 7, 13", "1, 2, 4, 13, 15"]
merged = merge(array_test)
as_int = list(map(int,merged))

print(merged)
print(as_int)
```

Output:

```
['1', '3', '4', '7', '13', '1', '2', '4', '13', '15']


[1, 3, 4, 7, 13, 1, 2, 4, 13, 15]
```

Without `as_int()`you will still hav strings in your list, you need to convert them into integers.

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension:

```
merged_arr = [n for s in array_test for n in s.split(", ")]
print(merged_arr)
```

This prints:

```
['1', '3', '4', '7', '13', '1', '2', '4', '13', '15']
```

Answer (score 1):

It merges this way because for lists `+=` is an array concatenation and that in this context your string object is interpreted as an array of characters:

```
[] += "Hello"
# Equivalent to 
[] += ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

If you want to join strings you can do:

```
out = "".join(array_test)
```